# Last object added is duplicated

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I think images are clearer so this code

```
    <c:forEach items="${empleado.ventas}" var="venta">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Número de venta</td>
            <td><c:out value="${venta.numero_factura}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Productos</td>
            <td><c:forEach items="${venta.productos}" var="producto">
                    <c:out value="${producto.nombreProducto}"></c:out>
                    <br>
                </c:forEach></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fecha de ingreso de la venta</td>
            <td><c:out value="${venta.fechaDeIngreso}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</c:forEach>
```

[return me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH8Ly.png)

After adding another sell,

[return me this (last sell is duplicated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw0U0.png)

This happens only in the view, the database insert works fine.

If I log out and log in, the view fixes.

Comment: Look at your implementation of "venta.productos", it's probably not JSTL misbehaving but your underlying "bean" returning duplicate objects.  You'll probably find the implemention in a getProductos() method.

Comment: Hi Dan, I comment that forEach and still happening. Any other idea ? The weird part is that when I log out and log in again the main forEach works properly. The problem is when I modify the session employee. I also tried to match the session employee with the database employee but the result it's the same. It only works when I finish the session and start a new one.

Comment: Thanks both, I resolve the problem. I was adding two times the @Id in ventas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was adding two times a sale in an employee**

This has no effect in database as the hibernate config is in update, but it had in the session object.